# remove a string inside a string with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to remove a part of a string like in the example below (with a regex and preg_replace) :

```
abcd,{{any_word |same_word_but_to_keep}},efg...
```

Result should be :

```
abcd,{{same_word_but_to_keep}},efg...
```

Any idea?

---

Another example :

```
Bellevue,Bergouey |Bergouey(tokeep),Bourdious
```

Results should be :

```
Bellevue,Bergouey,Bourdious
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what language? do you want this in

Comment: Until it is clear what is the pattern of the word or what are the words to be removed how are we supposed to answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I updated the question, maybe it's more clear like that, any idea how to build that regex?

Comment: Do you want any duplicates of a word following `|` to be removed? Could you add more examples?

Comment: yes, to remove the word duplicated with "|" just before the word to keep

Comment: I added one more example in the question, is it sthg possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
$str = 'Bellevue,Bergouey |Bergouey,Bourdious';
$str = preg_replace('~(\w+)\s*\|(\1)~', '$2', $str);
echo $str; //=> "Bellevue,Bergouey,Bourdious"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
preg_match_all("/\|(.*?) /", $your_string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    $your_string = preg_replace("/([^\|]|^)$match/", "", $your_string);
}
$your_string = preg_replace("/\|/", "", $your_string);
```

---

## How it works

- `preg_match_all("/\|(.*?) /", $your_string, $matches)` Gets all the words following `|`
- `preg_replace("/([^\|]|^)$match/", "", $your_string)` Removes all occurrences of the match not preceded by `|` and accounts for if the matching word is at the start of the string with `|^`
- `preg_replace("/\|/", "", $your_string)` Removes all occurances of `|` from the string

Comment: thank you OhAuth, but the words are not separated only with a space (can be also with a coma), I updated the question, the structure with duplicates is always between {{..}}, maybe it can make it eaisier, it's probably sthg stupid, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
preg_replace('/(\w+),(\w+)\s*\|\2,(.+)/', "$1,$2,$3", $string);
```

**Explanation:**

```
  (\w+) : group 1, a word
  ,     : a comma
  (\w+) : group 2, a word
  \s*   : white spaces, optional
  \|    : a pipe character
  \2    : back reference to group 2
  ,     : a comma
  (.+)  : rest of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution without a regex, it works perfectly :

```
$mystring="Arance,la Campagne,Gouze |Gouze,Lendresse";
$tmp="";
$words=explode(",",$mystring);
foreach($words as $word){
    if(strpos($word,"|")){
            $l=explode("|",$word);
            $tmp=$tmp.$l[1].",";
    }else{$tmp=$tmp.$word.",";}
}
$mystring=$tmp;
```